# Adding Collision Objects

Tags: ros, moveit, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to add collision objects to the planning scene interface. However, the moveit planning seems to ignore the collision objects. I am passing a list of boxes as collision objects. Here is the code:

```
moveit_utils::MicoController srv_controller;
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");
moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;
ROS_INFO("COLLISION SIZE\n");
ROS_INFO_STREAM(collision_objects.size());
sleep(2.0);
planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);

group.setPlanningTime(10.0); //5 second maximum for collision computation
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan my_plan;

group.setStartState(*group.getCurrentState());
group.setPoseTarget(p_target);

ROS_INFO("[mico_moveit_cartesianpose_service.cpp] starting to plan...");
bool success = group.plan(my_plan);
if(success)
    ROS_INFO("planning successful\n");
else 
    ROS_INFO("not successful :( \n");
```

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256409/adding-collision-objects/) by [palak_hirpara](https://answers.ros.org/users/29608/palak_hirpara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Either use the `applyCollisionObjects` method instead of `addCollisionObjects` or sleep again after you added the objects.
The latter function runs asynchronously and your planning request probably arrives before your collision object is processed.

Also see http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html#interlude-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-updates

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1